# How to multithread pygame.mixer sound into a tkinter program

Tags: python, python-3.7

I've created a tkinter program which uses a stopwatch class as the base of the whole program.  The stopwatch starts a -6 seconds and progresses to 0 and into the positive scale.
I've been successful in getting some 'drag tree lights' (graphics on the screen) to react to scheduled times when I run my app:-

Amber light 1 on -3 sec
Amber light 1 off Amber light 2 on -2 sec
Amber light 2 off Amber light 3 on -1 sec
Amber light 3 off Green light on 0.0 sec

There is also an event 'red light' for a false start (entering the field of play before the timer reaches 0.000 seconds).

My problem is that I want to add sound to this program so there are beeps with every incidence of the lights.

I ALMOST got this to work using pygame.mixer()

Despite getting the sounds to play, there is a slight delay from when they should play and the countdown beep doesn't sound consistent throughout.

My understanding from reading some of the Stackoverflow forum posts; I need to learn a technique called MULTI-THREADING to get this to work seamlessly.

Has anybody had any experience multi-threading pygame.mixer() with tkinter?
Can anybody point me in the right direction regarding useful tutorials on how to achieve my goal?
Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

I've contained all the sound processing in a class called (funnily enough) Sound.  There is a function for each of the 3 sounds I am using and I simply call these functions from the updater function of my stopwatch class.
The sounds are saved as 'ogg', as recommended in articles I've read about pygame.mixer()

## This is the class with the pygame.mixer() code:-

```
class Sound():

    mixer.init()                    

    def countbeep(self): 

        countbeep = mixer.Sound("CountBeep.ogg")
        countbeep.play()
        return      

    def gobeep(self):

        gobeep = mixer.Sound("GoBeep.ogg")
        gobeep.play()
        return

    def buzzer(self):

        buzzer = mixer.Sound("Buzzer.ogg")
        buzzer.play()
        return
```

## Here is an example of the updater code which calls one of the sound

## functions:

```
def Updater(self):
    self.totalTime = time.time() - self.startTime
    self.SetTime(self.totalTime)
    self.counter = float('%.1f' % self.totalTime)

    if self.counter == self.red_off:
        LightTree.redlite(self, False)

    if self.counter == -3.0:
        Sound.countbeep(self)
        LightTree.amber_1(self, True)
```

At the moment the program will execute with no error messages.  There is the issue with the slight delay when the sound comes on.  As this app is intended to be used as a sport trainer, the timing needs to be correct.  The 3 amber lights use the exact same sound, but at least one of them will sound out of phase when I execute my app.

Comment: It's beneficial to try yourself first, if you have a specific error or problem you're having implementing something, that's more along the lines of what SO is intended.

Comment: I understand, but I was hoping that maybe someone could point me in the right direction regarding literature and tutorial information.  I've been searching online for examples of threading, but they all seem to print dates to the command prompt.